# Detection of loudness of sound in android

Tags: android, audio, fft, threshold

I have written an app that records the sound of your environment using the built in microphone. I am trying to use this recorded data so that I can differentiate between loud environment sound and low environment sound.
   I have tried a Fourier transform on the recorded data and taking the log scale and tried thresholding it but its not accurate in differentiating these sounds. Is there any other way of doing it in software to differentiate dynamic range of sound of the surroundings?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use this api :

 public double getAmplitude() {
 if (mRecorder != null)
     return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
 else
     return 0;

 }
```

Refer this [DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)